# how get client side log messages into the server and keeping them into a file in gwt

Tags: gwt, logging

I've been trying to get the answer for this issue, I'm not getting that much great support from google.docs. Can anybody help me.

If you have a template on this please send it to this address:
uthicon.arun@gmail.com

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1) GWT 2.5 come with great logging api's. If you have not come across Dev Guided GWT logging then please refer https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging

2) You should opt for third party library like [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) only if the default logging in GWT lib is insufficient to avoid performance and maintenance issues.

3) You can download the samples from the following **[file](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.0.zip)**.

### Browse through sample code - [GWT samples for remote logging](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/logexample)

*How much more simpler do you want?*